# Exporting table names and columns in Excel with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I export only table names and its columns to an excel sheet from a database using Oracle SQL Developer version 4.

I tried exporting database feature, but it does not allow excel export for Metadata.

Sorry if this is asked in wrong forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query what you want eg:

```
select owner,table_name,column_name
from dba_tab_cols
where owner = 'SCHEMA';
```

Then `right click` on the result and choose `Eksport...`. Choose a format and save.